# Change left panel image of Preparing install dialog-Installer Schield

Tags: c#, wpf, installshield

I am working on “Installer shield limited edition” for create set up for  WPF (Framework  4.5) application.
Currently I am facing a problem related to “left panel image” of the first dialog in the installation process. Please find the image.

[image]

I have tried to change the left panel image and  tried to use our own image. But I couldn’t change this Image yet.
I am able to change all  other dialogs coming after the first dialog.

1. How can I change the  first dialog “Preparing to Install”  left panel image?
2. If not possible, is any other way to hide this dialog?

I am struggling with this issue.

3. Also I want  to uninstall the older version while installing the new  version of the application.

How can I accomplish this? Currently it is showing a message like “Another  Version exists”
Any help would be Appreciable.

Thanks

Ranish

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Finally I have solved this issue. I put the Setup.gif file to the installerScheild installed directory. C:\Program Files (x86)\InstallShield\2012SpringLE\Support\Themes\InstallShield Blue Theme.